# Como não serializar alguns atributos em chamadas RESTful (C# + WCF + JSON)?

Tags: c#, wcf, restful

No exemplo abaixo, como fazer para não serializar um atributo.

Acredito que procuro o equivalente da sintaxe java:

Para classes: @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true);
Para atributos: @JsonIgnore para atributo.

```
public class SomeFakeClass
{    
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

Como fazer para não serializar 1: a classe, 2:um atributo particular.

Desde de já obrigado!

Comment: Qual biblioteca voce esta usando para serializar o objeto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente usar o atributo [`IgnoreDataMemberAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute(v=vs.100).aspx) na propriedade.

Exemplo com a propriedade `ID` da sua classe:

```
public class SomeFakeClass
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito Miguel! Obrigado!